# BulkWrite(with upsert) to Sharded Mongo Collection failing to upsert

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot

Im trying to update records in a sharded collection. I essentially do it via a list where I create a UpdateOneModel and gather them all before I upsert. I then do an BulkWrite with bulkWriteOptions set but I get an error then

> 'Failed to target upsert by query :: could not extract exact shard key'

Im unsure of how to solve this as most answers Ive read say to use `multi: true` but i cant find this in any of the options objects I set. Is there a way to set this in java?

An snip of the code

The bulk write setup

```
List<WriteModel<Document>> bulkWrites = new ArrayList<>();
BulkWriteOptions bulkWriteOptions = new BulkWriteOptions();
bulkWriteOptions.ordered(false);
bulkWriteOptions.bypassDocumentValidation(false);
```

The UpdateOneModel creation (thats within a loop)

```
Document filterDocument = new Document("_id", object.getId());
Document updateDocument = new Document("$set", object.getUpdate());
UpdateOptions updateOptions = new UpdateOptions();
updateOptions.upsert(true);
UpdateOneModel<Document> updateOne = new UpdateOneModel<>(
    filterDocument,
    updateDocument,
    updateOptions
);
bulkWrites.add(updateOne);
```

Then the bulkWrite itself

```
collection.bulkWrite(bulkWrites, bulkWriteOptions);
```

A sample of the update would be

```
 //  _id and info.data are indexes
{
    _id: 'abc',
    type: 'typeA',
    stats: {},
    values: {},
    info: {
        data: "something"
    }
}
```

where the upsert will either create a new obejct or update an existing object's `stats` and `values`

Comment: Show us one update statement and a sample document

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit sorry cant put up actual data hopefully that helps

Comment: Review https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.update/#sharded-collections

Comment: Which of the fields in that update is the shard key?